# When should version tags be added to a question?

Tags: discussion

Firstly, in the spirit of full disclosure, this question is directly in response to an edit I made to a post that I later found had been rejected as can be seen below.

[image]

---

I make use of tags to filter posts throughout all of StackExchange and thought others do as well. I was kind of set back after seeing that the edit was rejected and reading the reason for rejection cause more confusion.

Searching for an answer to this question quickly led to ***numerous*** posts about "tag spamming" and others asking how to prevent this "useless editing" of adding tags to posts. It appears there is or was some bitterness regarding tag edits.

The [tagging help page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) clearly encourages this behavior.

> Re-tagging
>
> As part of the [editing process](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/editing), users may suggest edits or directly
>   edit the tags of a question if they feel a certain tag was used
>   inappropriately or that the question is missing a tag.
>
> You should re-tag questions when:
>
> - You are adding valuable information to the question by doing so
> - You are replacing obscure or difficult to understand tags with well-known
>     and popular tags that are appropriate for the question.

I encourage general discussion on this topic and ultimately would like to reach an understanding as to when version tags should and should not be added to questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To me this is clearly a mistake from reviewers. This edit should have been approved as adding the 2.1 tag helps narrowing the issue even if it's already stated in the question.

Regarding version tags, I tend to do the following depending on the number of tags left:

- add the major version tag e.g magento-2.1
- add the magento2 or magento-1 tag
- add the minor version tag e.g magento-2.1.0

It is always better to add miscellaneous tags than adding only version tags to me so I tend to only do the first two of my list.

Comment: Absolutely agree. Every question should have a version tag because it might matter to someone who knows the answer, not necessarily the OP.